My profile page says I have answered no questions
When I go to my profile page, or whatever you call it, and look at Summary and the headings below it.
It states under questions, that I have not answered any questions.
How can that be?
Quote: You have not answered any questions

You're looking at your Meta profile. Your main profile shows all your answers.

Ah, well, now that's clear. Thanks. Do you think I should pose a question about how this site handles AI stuff? There's an entire page of posts on SE about that with a list of all the sites and their policies. Don't you think we need one? Sorry to ask you here first but I don't want to be a bother.

No that would be fine. It's an important topic to discuss
